# Matlab - Concatenation of overlapping blocks with weighted average

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I'm looking for a quick way to combine **overlapping** blocks into one image. Assume the size of the full image and the coordinates of each block within the full image are known. Also assume the blocks are regularly spaced both horizontally and vertically.

The catch - in the overlapping region, a pixel in the output image should get a value according to a weighted average of the corresponding pixels in the overlapping blocks. The weights should be proportional to the distance from the block center.

So, for example, take a pixel location `p` (relative to the full image coordinates) in the overlapping region between block `B1` and `B2`. Assume the overlap region is due to a horizontal shift only of size `h`. If `B1(p)` and `B2(p)` are the values at that location as they appear in blocks `B1`,`B2`, and `d1`,`d2` are the respective distances of `p` from the center of blocks `B1` and `B2` then in the output image `O` the location `p` will get `O(p) = (h-d1)/h*B1(p) + (h-d2)/h*B2(p)`.

Note that generally, there can be up to 4 overlapping blocks in any region.

I'm looking for the best way to do this in Matlab. Hopefully, for any choice of distance function.

`blockproc` and alike can help splitting an image into blocks but allow for very basic combination of results. `imfuse` comes close to what I need, but offers simple non-weighted alpha blending only. `bwdist` seems to be useful, but I haven't figured what the most efficient method to put it to use is.

Comment: Are you implementing the BM3D algorithm?

Comment: @Drazick, nope. Just looking to merge results from some image processing that can not be done on the entire image and so is done in blocks.

Comment: It sounds like the merging step in BM3D which means you can look for reference implementations of it and just do the same.

Comment: @Drazick, I agree, the concept of accumulating a weights and values buffer and then using the quotient between them fits my needs. However, I haven't found a Matlab (non-mex) implementation for this. I admit my question is not on the concept but rather on whether there is a 'quick and elegant' way of doing this that will handle all the annoying edge cases, evenly sized blocks (which have no center) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the command [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html).
Once you have all your patches in vectors aligned in one matrix you'll be able to work on the columns (Filtering per patch) and rows (Filtering between patches).

It will be trickier than the classic usage of `im2col` but it should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have to disagree here and say that `blockproc` with it's optional border parameters is a better fit. `im2col` generates every possible block which is simply impractical for my needs. More importantly, this does not help towards the **fusion** of results using a weighted average (or at least, I don't see how it does).